# Emscripten - passing command line arguments

Tags: javascript, c

I have a C program "translated" (dont know what word is appropiate) to Javascript, so I can use it in node.js.
C program consists of main that accepts command line parameters. I understand that I need to somehow use module object to pass those command line arguments, but I'm at a loss.

My js program consists of 2 files: program.js (C program compiled into js) and test.js (var module = require('./program.js'), and the rest that operates on this imported program.

The question is: How do I pass some arguments to this C-translated-to-javascript-and-then-imported program?

Comment: What's wrong with manipulating [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)?

Answer (score 14):

Emscripten has a global object called [Module](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/module.html), which has [arguments](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/module.html#Module.arguments) property. This property contains array of arguments that will get passed in. Just set them before letting emscripten run the compiled program.

Like so, in javascript:

```
Module['arguments'].push('first_param');
Module['arguments'].push('second_param');
```

In C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(argc == 3);
    assert(strcmp(argv[1], "first_param") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(argv[2], "second_param") == 0);
}
```

Alternatively you may consider to not build your C code as executable with a main function, but rather as a library that exposes individual C functions to the javascript. Then those functions can have nicely named and typed arguments and you can pass the arguments (almost) directly from javascript when calling them.

Comment: after one pushes the arguments, how do you run the main?

Comment: If you are building a binary with emscripten, it will call the `main` for you. To set the arguments before that, it must be done in javascript file given to the `--pre-js` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `callMain()` and it worked. Also I had to set `Module.arguments: [ 'my','arguments'],` in the same place all other parameters are set in the HTML so they were set before initializing arguments. BUT IT WORKED! This is super magical.